# Properly seeding rand_r(int *val) method

Tags: c, pointers

So I have multiple threads which will be using the rand_r function. The signature of this function is :

```
int rand_r(int *val);
```

I was trying to use the time to seed this function but I'm having all kinds of trouble. Could anyone explain to me how I would call rand_r using time, or some other simple way to seed rand_r dynamically.

Thanks!

Comment: please refer to the manual-> http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r

Comment: What are all kinds of troubles? Please be specific so we can help.

Comment: Hi @Thomas I tried to use all forms of this. And I'm having a lot of trouble with pointers I guess. I tried to do: rand_r((unsigned int*)time(null)) and I didn't get an issue compiling, but got segmentation fault when running.

Comment: @user1742385, rand_r modifies the parameter and you are passing it a temporary variable that will go out of scope as soon as the rand_r function is entered. You should create a variable for your seed and use that as the argument

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the reentrant version `rand_r`, the seed is just the initial value of the state .You need one seed per thread. Either create an array of seeds, or make the seed variable thread-local:

```
_Thread_local unsigned int seed = time(NULL);

int do_stuff()
{
    for ( ; ; )
    {
        int n = rand_r(&seed);
        // use n
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using a brand new and shiny C11 feature `_Thread_local`. One should perhaps add that not all compilers support that directly, yet, but maybe have extension that are similar, that thread support in C11 is optional, and that the indicated use is to include "threads.h" and use the nicer macro `thread_local`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

On a UNIX/POSIX system you can open `/dev/urandom` for initial random numbers, reading enough bytes to get a seed for each thread. Microsoft Windows has a more elaborate way to get such numbers. Look up **CryptGenRandom** for details. As these are based on system entropy they are not for high volume random numbers.